# Most labels update well, except for one

Tags: python, tkinter

I apologize for pasting all of my code. I'm at a loss as to how I should post this question. I did look for other answers throughout this week, but I cannot for the life of me figure this out. I know that there is more I have to do to get this program to work, but I'm just trying to get the team_at_play label to update. I've tried printing the variables and team_at_play.set() and team_at_play = team_b.get(). The print team_at_play.get() shows the team whose turn it is, but the label does not update.

Also, have I put the functions, like coin_toss(), etc. in the right place with respect to the mainloop?

Here is a link to a text file that can be loaded from the menu item: "Abrir Capitulo":

http://www.mariacarrillohighschool.com/Teachers/JamesBaptista/Spanish7-8/ClassDocuments/Handouts/expres_1_1.txt

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
## Recall Game

"""This will be a timed game of vocabulary recall that will focus on
all the previous units studied. If possible, the sessions will have
a time limit, so teams might compete against one another.
Teams will win points according to how many answers are given correctly.
Questions will be randomly selected."""
import sys
import time
import csv
import StringIO
import random
import string
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkFont

def score_calc (answer):
##Returns a point value for the expression in play
    score = 0
    ##print ('Answer'), answer
    for i in len(answer): ##Thanks to user2357112
        score += 1
    return score 


master = Tk()
master.title("Araña en la Cabaña")
master.geometry=("800x800+200+200")
master.configure(background="black")

from random import choice
d={}
team_A= StringVar()
team_B= StringVar()
team_A_score= IntVar()
team_B_score= IntVar()
team_at_play = StringVar()
pregunta = StringVar()
answer = StringVar()
turn = 0

correct_answer = StringVar()

feedback=StringVar()
correct = ['!Sí!', '¡Muy bien!', '¡Excelente!', '¡Fabuloso!']
incorrect =['¡Caramba!', '¡Ay, ay, ay!', '¡Uy!']


def select_expression():
## Returns at random an expression
    ##print ('select_expression beginning')
#     print len(d)
    selected_question = ''
    global pregunta
    print ('select_expression at work')
    try:
        selected_question =random.choice(d.keys()) ##Problem selecting random key
        pregunta.set(selected_question)
        print 'Pregunta =', pregunta.get()
        answer.set(d[selected_question])
        print 'Answer =', answer.get()
        ##return pregunta  Thanks to user2357112
        ##return answer    Thanks to user2357112
    except IndexError:
        print ('Error')
        pass
    ##print pregunta

def coin_toss ():
## Tosses a coin to see who goes first. Returns even or odd integer
    print ('Coin toss at work.')
    from random import randint
    coin_toss = randint(0,1)
    if coin_toss == 0:
        turn = 3
    if coin_toss == 1:
        turn = 4
    return turn      

def player_turn():
## Prompts players or teams during turns. Updates scoreboard.
    print ('Player_turn() at work.')
    global team_at_play
    global turn    
    while turn < 1:
        turn = coin_toss()
        team_A_score.set(0)
        team_B_score.set(0)
        print 'turn =', turn

    if turn %2== 0:
        print 'turn=',turn
        print ('Team_B:'), team_B.get()
        team_at_play= team_B.get()
        print 'Team_at_play:', team_at_play
        select_expression()

    if turn %2!= 0:
        print 'Turn=', turn
        print ('Team_A:'), team_A.get()
        team_at_play= team_A.get()
        print 'Team_at_play:', team_at_play
        select_expression()

def nombrar_equipos():
    nombrar_equipos = Toplevel()
    ##Dialog box for entering the team names.


    nombrar_equipos.title("Nombrar los Equipos")
    first_team_label = Label(nombrar_equipos,text="El primer equipo:")
    first_team_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

    second_team_label = Label(nombrar_equipos,text="El segundo equipo:")
    second_team_label.grid(column=0, row=0)
    team_A_entry = Entry(nombrar_equipos,width =20, textvariable=team_A)
    team_A_entry.grid(column=1, row=0)
    team_A_entry.focus_set()
    team_B_entry = Entry(nombrar_equipos, width =20, textvariable=team_B)
    team_B_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)
    entregar_button=Button(nombrar_equipos, text ="Entregar", command=nombrar_equipos.destroy)
    entregar_button.grid(column=1,row=2)


def abrir_capitulo():
    ##Dialog box for selecting the chapter to be loaded.
    #this will hide the main window
    import tkFileDialog
    WORDLIST_FILENAME = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=master,title="Archivo para abrir", defaultextension=".txt")
    global d
    d = {}
    with open(WORDLIST_FILENAME) as fin:
            rows = (line.split('\t') for line in fin)
            d = {row[0]:row [1] for row in rows}
    for k in d:
         d[k]= d[k].strip('\n')
    ## print ('Line 68')
    inv_d = {v:k for k, v in d.items()}
     ##print inv_d
    d.update(inv_d)
    print d
    print ('¡'), len(d), ('expresiones cargadas!')
    return d

def check_response(*args):
        ##checks a team's answer, rewards points if correct.
        if team_at_play.get() == team_A.get():
            if team_answer==answer:
                team_A_score.set(team_A_score.get() + score_calc (d[pregunta]))
                turn += 1

            if team_answer != answer:
                turn += 1

        if team_at_play.get() == team_B.get():
            if team_answer==answer:
                team_B_score.set(team_B_score.get() + score_calc (d[pregunta]))
                turn += 1

            if team_answer != answer:
                turn += 1


class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)

        master.puntuacion= Label(master, text="Araña en la Cabaña", font=("American Typewriter", 30),bg="black", fg="red", justify=CENTER)
        master.puntuacion.grid(row=0, column=2)

        master.team_A_label= Label(master, textvariable= team_A, font=("American Typewriter", 24),bg="black", fg="red")
        master.team_A_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
        master.team_B_label= Label(master, textvariable= team_B, font=("American Typewriter", 24),bg="black", fg="red")
        master.team_B_label.grid(row=1, column=3)

        master.team_A_score_label= Label(master, textvariable= team_A_score, font=("04B", 24),bg="black", fg="yellow").grid(row=2, column=1)
        # team_A_score_label= tkFont.Font(family="Times", size=20, weight=bold, color=red)
        master.team_B_score_label= Label(master, textvariable= team_B_score, font=("04B", 24),bg="black", fg="yellow")
        master.team_B_score_label.grid(row=2, column=3)

        master.team_at_play_label= Label(master, textvariable= team_at_play, font=("American Typewriter", 24),fg="yellow", bg="black")
        master.team_at_play_label.grid(row=4, column=2)

        master.pregunta_start = Label(master, text="¿Cómo se traduce....?", font=("American Typewriter", 24),fg="blue",bg="black")
        master.pregunta_start.grid(row=6, column=2)

        master.pregunta_finish = Label(master, textvariable = pregunta, font=("American Typewriter", 24),fg="green",bg="black")
        master.pregunta_finish.grid(row=7, column=2)

        master.team_answer = Entry(master, width=50)
        master.team_answer.grid(row=8, column=2)
        master.team_answer.focus_set()
        master.feedback_label = Label(textvariable= feedback, font=("American Typewriter", 24),fg="green",bg="black")
        master.feedback_label.grid(row=9, column=2)

        respond_button = Button(master, text="Responder",bg="black", command=check_response, justify=CENTER, borderwidth=.001)
        respond_button.grid(row=10, column=3)
        master.bind("<Return>", check_response)

        continue_button = Button(master, text="Adelante", bg="black", command=player_turn)
        continue_button.grid(row=10, column=4)        

menubar = Menu(master)
filemenu= Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Nombrar Equipos",command=nombrar_equipos)
filemenu.add_command(label="Abrir Capítulo",command=abrir_capitulo)

filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label="Cerrar", command=master.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Archivo",menu=filemenu)
master.config(menu=menubar)




master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
app= App(master)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are you expecting two return statements in a row to do? You have two in a row in `select_expression`; the second one will never be reached, because the first one is in the way.

Comment: Why does `score_calc` loop over its input? It looks like you could just use `len(answer)`.

Comment: user2357112: Thank you. I put those there because I'm unsure if the both of those variables will be updated outside of the function. Is it possible to return two variables like: return answer, pregunta?

Comment: Yes. The syntax is exactly `return answer, pregunta`. Why would you do that, though? `answer` and `pregunta` are both global variables.

Comment: User2357112: Please disregard the previous comment.

Comment: user2357112: Thank you. I put two returns there because I'm unsure if the both of those variables will be updated outside of the function. I suppose, though, that I do not need to return anything since a few lines above I used the pregunta.set(selected_expression). I don't know how to respond to your question about score_calc. My understanding is that "for i in answer" means that for every character in the string "answer", do this. Should I just use len(answer) instead?

Comment: If you want the length of a string, `len(answer)` gets you that. Looping over the characters of the string is unnecessary.

Comment: Okay. Can you see anything funky with that label?

Comment: Nope. I don't know Tkinter; I'm pointing out errors and abnormalities that don't relate to that.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a change to player_turn(). I experimented with changing the textvariable for different labels in the master frame and decided that the problem was isolated to player_turn. Then I looked at the difference between that and the other functions I had written. There might be a better way to set a StringVar equal to another, but I came up with this, which is to create an intermediate variable to which I set team_at_play.

```
def player_turn():
## Prompts players or teams during turns. Updates scoreboard.
    print ('Player_turn() at work.')
#     global team_at_play
    global turn    
    while turn < 1:
        turn = coin_toss()
        team_A_score.set(0)
        team_B_score.set(0)
        print 'turn =', turn

    if turn %2== 0:
        print 'turn=',turn
        print ('Team_B:'), team_B.get()
        playing_team= team_B.get()
        team_at_play.set(playing_team)
        print 'Team_at_play:', team_at_play
        select_expression()

    if turn %2!= 0:
        print 'Turn=', turn
        print ('Team_A:'), team_A.get()
        playing_team=team_B.get()
        team_at_play.set(playing_team)
        print 'Team_at_play:', team_at_play
        select_expression()
```